# Error Handling in Windows Service

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services, error-handling

How can i write generic error handler in my windows service? I tried the following code in OnStart method but it is not catching the exceptions.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new 
UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptionTrapper);
                this.Start();
}
```

Is there something i am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably getting exceptions on background threads.  Wrap all code in all event handlers in try/catch blocks.